# Echo images into table from database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to create a column that echo's images from the database. So i got as far as echoing the field but i don't know how to echo the image source with it, help please!

```
echo "<td>" . $row['images'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: How your image stored in database? Is it a link?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it's stored from my file directory eg. images/cake.jpg

Comment: So what is content of `$row['images']`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving your image source on the db correctly, you should add an img tag, like this:

```
echo '<td><img src="' . $row['images'] . '" /></td>';
```

Of course, thats assuming you are saving the source

Comment: do i need to specify the file directory after img src=?

Comment: if you have your image stored inside your project, you can use relative paths, for instance if your project is in a folder named "myproject" and that folder contains a folder named img, then your relative path for your image is: "/img/nameoffile.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

1. Build full link to image
2. Correctly output it with html i.e. use `<img>` tag.

You can build full link to image by adding `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` before src from your database.

Code:

```
$imageSrc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['images'];
echo "<td><img src='$imageSrc' /></td>";
```

Check what is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` content.

For example:

- it will be `/home/site/www`, so you have to add `/` symbol between it
  and entry from the database.
- it will be `/home/site/www/`, so you
  don't need to add `/`

This will work, if you have such path to `images` directory: `/home/site/www/images`.